# Limit time between nodes in ortools

Tags: or-tools

I am using this example.

https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrptw

and I am trying to limit the maximum time between two nodes.

```
routing.addDimension(transitCallbackIndex, // transit callback
30, // allow waiting time
30, // vehicle maximum capacities
false, // start cumul to zero
"Time");
```

I am trying to change the highlighted value, but it is for the maximum time a vehicle can travel not the maximum time between two nodes.

Can someone please suggest is there a way where I can limit the maximum time between two nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

already answered on the ortools-discuss mailing list: https://groups.google.com/g/or-tools-discuss/c/P3RZ_d_BCZ8

- You'll need to register one Callback per maximum limit time if you have several.
- To forbid an arc simply have your callback returning a number > to the vehicle maximum capacity so the solver can't pickup otherwise it will violate the vehicle maximum capacity constraint ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here how I achieved the above.

```java
    private static LongBinaryOperator distanceCallback(
                RoutingIndexManager manager, SolverRequest solverRequest, int vehicleIndex) {
            return (firstIndex, secondIndex) -> {
                int firstNode = manager.indexToNode(firstIndex);
                int secondNode = manager.indexToNode(secondIndex);
                Vehicle vehicle = solverRequest.vehicles[vehicleIndex];
                long distance =  //get the distance between first node and second node for given vehicle.
                if (distance > vehicle.getMaxInterNodeDistance().) {
                    //This will not be accepted.
                    return vehicle.getMaxTravelDistance()+1;
                }
                else
                    return distance;
            };
        }
```

Comment: What is `SolverRequest`? i can not import it from ortool lib